# Python: joining two dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One data is an annexe explaining the code and the other is the mining information. I need the data connection of the second data to extract the information according to that code in the first dataframe.

Table 1:

| Numero | Date | Version | Origine | Destination | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;686006;AN |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;686006;P6 |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;6866675;1P |

Table 2:

| Code 1 | Code 2 | Info 1 | Info 2 | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000654 | LO | Mcdo | London | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |
| 000654 | AN | Mcdo | NYC | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |
| 686006 | 1P | KFC | Paris | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |
| 686006 | AN | KFC | NYC | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |
| 074590 | AT | Start | LA | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |
| 688975 | AN | Hight | NYC | 01/02/2002 | 01/02/2021 |

In "Origine", "Destination", "Other": numero order, code 1, code 2.

So I need to join two table with conditions "Code 1", "Code 2" to give informations orders  "Info 1" and "info 2".

Output:

| Numero | Date | Version | Origine | Destination | Other | Info Origine | Info Destination | Info Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;686006;AN | KFC NYC | Start LA | KFC NYC |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;686006;P6 | KFC NYC | Start LA |  |
| 1111 | 01/11/2009 | 5 | 0065;686006;AN | 0065;74590;AT | 0065;6866675;1P | KFC NYC | Start LA |  |

PLEASE HELP ME! THANKS YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long way to do this but it's clear in it's steps. Others may adapt to be more efficient. See comment within merge area - your data isn't the same format so you have to account for leading zeroes if you go with this method.

Basically, I create common columns in each table and perform multiple merges, cleaning the tables as I go.

```
import io

d1 = '''Numero  Date    Version Origine Destination Other
1111    01/11/2009  5   0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT   0065;686006;AN
1111    01/11/2009  5   0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT   0065;686006;P6
1111    01/11/2009  5   0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT   0065;6866675;1P'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d1), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df1['OrigineCode1Code2'] = df1['Origine'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
df1['DestinationCode1Code2'] = df1['Destination'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
df1['OtherCode1Code2'] = df1['Other'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]


d2 = '''Code 1  Code 2  Info 1  Info 2  Date 1  Date 2
000654  LO  Mcdo    London  01/02/2002  01/02/2021
000654  AN  Mcdo    NYC 01/02/2002  01/02/2021
686006  1P  KFC Paris   01/02/2002  01/02/2021
686006  AN  KFC NYC 01/02/2002  01/02/2021
074590  AT  Start   LA  01/02/2002  01/02/2021
688975  AN  Hight   NYC 01/02/2002  01/02/2021'''

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d2), sep=' \s+', engine='python', dtype='str')
df2['Code1Code2'] = df2.apply( lambda x: ';'.join([x['Code 1'], x['Code 2']]), axis=1)
df2['Info1Info2'] = df2.apply( lambda x: ' '.join([x['Info 1'], x['Info 2']]), axis=1)

df = df1.merge(df2[['Code1Code2', 'Info1Info2']], left_on='OrigineCode1Code2', right_on='Code1Code2', how='left')
df.drop(['OrigineCode1Code2', 'Code1Code2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# NOTE: 074590 in table 1 is different from table 2 due to leading zero; you'll have to fix that somehow as you
# won't get any matches during the merge
df = df.merge(df2[['Code1Code2', 'Info1Info2']], left_on='DestinationCode1Code2', right_on='Code1Code2', how='left')
df.drop(['DestinationCode1Code2', 'Code1Code2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(df2[['Code1Code2', 'Info1Info2']], left_on='OtherCode1Code2', right_on='Code1Code2', how='left')
df.drop(['OtherCode1Code2', 'Code1Code2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.rename(columns={'Info1Info2_x':'Info Origine', 'Info1Info2_y':'Info Destination', 'Info1Info2':'Info Other'}, inplace=True)
df
```

Output

```
   Numero        Date  Version         Origine    Destination            Other Info Origine Info Destination Info Other
0    1111  01/11/2009        5  0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT   0065;686006;AN      KFC NYC              NaN    KFC NYC
1    1111  01/11/2009        5  0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT   0065;686006;P6      KFC NYC              NaN        NaN
2    1111  01/11/2009        5  0065;686006;AN  0065;74590;AT  0065;6866675;1P      KFC NYC              NaN        NaN
```

Comment: You’re welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi, 
for example, i have a condition: 
1/ 686006;AN and 686006;P6
or 2/ 686006;P6 and 6866675;DT

How can I select the corresponding values ​​into a new file?

Comment: Sorry. Don’t follow your question. You can edit your question with new scenarios or open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks your support, i opened new topic for this question. And thanks you so much if you can see and help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/69451808/17037971

Comment: @Poohlikepooh did you find the answer to your new question? I see you deleted it.

Comment: thank you, i found the answer; have a good day